# Disable "email" Sign Up/Login in Lock

Tags: auth0

Disclaimer: This is more of an Auth0 Lock question--there isn't an "Auth0-Lock" tag yet, if someone with 1500+ rep wants to create one.

Anyone know how or if there is a way to make it so Lock does not show the email/username and password fields on the login tab, as well as the email, username, and password fields on the Sign Up tab?

[image]

Comment: So you want to disable username/password authentication altogether and use only social connections, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The search results from Auth0's site took me to old documentation.

Solution:

the OPTIONS object you can pass into the lockProvider accepts a property called "allowedConnections", which is an array of string values. I just had to list the connection options I wanted to be ALLOWED rather than letting it show all the connections I have available for the app.

Documentation for Lock v10:
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#allowedconnections-array-

Comment: If you *really* want to disable username/password authentication, turn this connection off in your app dashboard, this will automatically remove the option from lock too. If you just hide it in the UI, it's still possible to create users programmatically.

Comment: Good call. Unfortunately, I have instances where that piece is used so I can't disable it globally. :/ (You hit the nail on the head, we're programmatically creating "users" after all of the FB bits complete)

Comment: People getting here might assume this is a valid solution, while it is not. If the business logic forbids user creating a user for themselves (e.g. internal enterprise app), blocking it in the client is a serious security risk. Even if for your specific use case this is something you can live with, for most other user cases it's not.

Comment: Elad—Can you explain why using the built-in functionality of Lock isn’t correct? I’m not being a jerk, I genuinely want to understand what you’re getting at. (Lock was still using Auth0 to create users)

Answer (score 2):

The follow allows users to log in but not to sign up with a username/password:

- manage.auth0.com
- Connections
- Database
- Username-Password-Authentication
- Settings
- Disable Sign Ups

---

[image]

Comment: Yeah, when I posted this, that was available at the time as well, but we needed to have the user in multiple sources--don't ask why... we didn't want to do it but that's how we kept moving forward in the early stages.